# update vue2 to vue3 on Laravel 5.5 (node 12)

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vuejs3

i unable to find any solution to integrate Laravel 5.5 with vue3, is it possible to integrate?

```
// resources/js/app.js

// Import Vue.js
import { createApp } from 'vue';

// Import your Vue components
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';

// Create a Vue application instance
const app = createApp({});

// Register your Vue components globally
// app.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

// Mount the Vue application instance to a DOM element
app.mount('#app');
```

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

currently I follow these steps and also tried with inertiajs but any option is not working as expected

Comment: You should describe the actual issue.  What does "not working as expected" mean?  It's too ambiguous.  Vue 3 I will point out though [requires node.js 18.0 or higher](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application), while according to your title you're only on node 12.